# phonegap ondevice ready not firing first time when ripple is loading

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am working on phonegap when i run my app in ripple emulator my onDeviceReady is not firing but when i refresh the link from ripple emulator it fire onDeviceReady function and display data what is the wrong with that my code is:

```
   function onDeviceReady() {
        db.transaction(sucessQueryDB, errorCB);
        db.transaction(getTitle, errorCB);
    }
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

why my code is not running on first time i already did check on android device when first time app load its empty when i exit and run it again data is display

Comment: did you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
      db.transaction(sucessQueryDB, errorCB);
      db.transaction(getTitle, errorCB);
 },true);
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: i already tried that code but still not working data is coming when app run second time